# Black screen on boot and wake - HP Pavilion Dv6

Tags: boot, screen, hp-pavilion

I failed to find a clean answer to this issue. HP Pavilion Dv6, just installed Ubuntu 12.10 after Windows 7 got too annoying. Ubuntu is currently the only OS on the laptop.

I used to only have 12.04 on here, and everything worked fine. Anyways my issue is, Every time i wake the computer from sleep mode, it only shows a black screen but still seems to be working according to the HDD light.

A similar issue occurs EVERY time i try booting the computer; it boots to a purple screen, then turns black. But when i hold the power button and try again, it always boots just fine.

Comment: if you have an ati card you are unlucky. I used to have this problem in 11.04 but it had been solved when I upgraded to 11.10 and on ward

Answer (score 1):

I have a DV6. In fact I'm on it at the moment.

I don't know what variant of the DV6 you own. I'm assuming you have a variant with the Nvidia or ATI card. Go to SOFTWARE SOURCES and the last tab should be proprietary drivers. Go ahead and enable the recommended driver. The ADDITIONAL DRIVERS option has be removed as it appears that JOCKEY-GTK has been merged with SOFTWARE SOURCES. Cheers.